# ReactJS Webpack not found

Tags: reactjs

I am facing issues related to React. I recently installed react router in my project after installation error is exist **module.js** 544 throw error and webpack not found. i am also attaching the error, webpack config and package.json file in ScreenShot.
[ScreenShot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sbmA.jpg)

```js
{
  "name": "c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A quiz app related to author of books",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "transpiling",
    "es6"
  ],
  "author": "Munib Habib",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `webpack` as a `devDependency` before using it,

To install it for the current project, Install it using

```
npm run --save-dev webpack
```

and then run

```
webpack
```

Comment: before adding router functionality it was running successfully.

Comment: Try installing it before using